# read in data from input file into class method

Tags: java

I am trying to read information from a file thats in the format

1 2 4 5

6 7

8 9 10 11

etc

with either 2 or 4 values

I am trying to figure our how to read in the input from a file, as of now I have so the information is read

```
while(myReader.hasNextLine())
       {
           String inData= myReader.nextLine();
           
            data=inData.split(inData);
```

to continue reading until the file is done

I need to know how to take these split string arrays into usable numbers to use in a method that's dependent on how many values are in each line (either 2 or 4). String split will convert the information from the file into an array of strings in each line but how can I convert this into numerical values to use in my methods?

Comment: You can use `Integer.parseInt(**yourstringhere**)` on each of the array locations to convert them to integers.

Comment: You might find that `inData.split(" ")` works better than `inData.split(inData)`.  An alternative to using `split` and `Integer.parseInt` would be to use a second `Scanner` that just parses each line.